# SSRS for AS calculated measures showing zero in deployed reports - shows numbers in Preview

Tags: ssas-2012, reporting-services-2012

I am working on AR_Aging reports.  Naturally,  I have a number of calendar lag measures.  I created them in SSRS rather than in the cube.  They show the correct numbers in the Preview, but show only zeros in the deployed report in the web. The calculated measures are like this:
 SUM([Calendar].[Month].Currentmember.lag(2),[Measures].[Ledger Balance])
with various Month lags.  Ledger_Balance is a measure directly from the cube.  Do I need to move these calculated measures into the cube?  Is that the issue?  Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need go to Visual Studio and add the following calculated measure onto the MDX Script of the cube on the Calculations tab of the Cube Editor in SSRS.

See: https://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/category/reporting-services/